# Exclude keypress from certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to catch spacebar and below did catch it. However it's tied to document, the catch will trigger even if I press spacebar when I'm typing in an input box. How to exclude that?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 32) {
        alert('trigger');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nodeName` to catch the event source:
http://jsfiddle.net/t8jqb2rq/

```
//Array of sources you want to include
var includeIn = ['BODY','TEXTAREA'];
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 32 && includeIn.indexOf(e.target.nodeName) != -1) {
        alert('trigger');
    }

 });
```

Comment: why u include textarea? textarea shouldn't trigger anything which we want to allow user to type, am i correct?

Comment: I included that just to demonstrate the usage (see in the fiddle). you can just leave 'BODY' (document). obviously you can do the same opposite and make an 'exclude' array that contains only sources you will to catch spacebar in, and use in..

Comment: I see. thanks so much although I did not know how to use e.target.nodeName lol